# What features boost security for a home edge router?

Tags: network, webserver, routing

I want to hide my home network behind a router and not worry about firewalls on internet-facing devices. Furthermore, one PC is going to be hosting some services, so I guess I need port forwarding as well. It would be also nice if this PC is somewhat detached from the LAN, so that if a breach is successful upon it, only the server is compromised, and not my home LAN.

What features do I need to look for in a router, in order to achieve the above? Please also link to tutorials how to do it e.g. firewall configuration.

Comment: So why the downvote? I am completely clueless in this area. A google search yielded things like "Top 10 home routers", with a $230 apple hotspot, that is stylishly white, being the definite #1.

Answer (score 1):

You would look for a network setup that includes a "DMZ" (demilitarized zone) or service network.  This network is accessible from the external network (i.e the Internet), but it cannot "jump" to your secured, internal network.

- Basically, your internal network can access the Internet and your DMZ server.
- The Internet can only reach your DMZ server.
  (Not counting response packets)

It really depends on your router's software how you configure it, a good generic writeup could be found at Wikipedia's page about DMZ's: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_(computing)